# swift localization cannot find value for key

Tags: swift, localization

i'm trying to import strings through my localizeable.strings. Unfortunately its only displaying the key in my button. Please find attached my file tree:

[image: file tree]

and here is my project info:

[image: project info]

here are my localizeable.strings files (both the same to test if its working)

```
"You have sold 1000 apps in %d months" = "You have sold 1000 apps in %d months";
 "You like?" = "You asdflike?";
```

and here is how i try to get the value You asdflike?

```
    likeButton.setTitle(NSLocalizedString("You like?", comment: "You like the result?"),
            for: .normal)
}
```

unfortunately its just showing the key instead of the result . I actually dont know what i did wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue seems to be because of the file name. Rename the file to `Localizable.strings`.